# How to edit package source code?

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the source code files for move base with apt-get source, but how do i put them in move_base directory so i can edit them there and it gets saved and compiled??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301632/how-to-edit-package-source-code?/) by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a variety of old answers that walk through this process: #q252478 is one.  You'll want to git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git (package wiki pages usually link to the source repo pages) to put the source into a catkin_ws instead of using apt-get.  If you source devel/setup.sh after building you'll be using the customized version of move_base instead of the one perhaps already installed with apt.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-26**:
@lucasw: @topkek has used `apt-get source`. That got him the sources of `move_base` as they were used to build the currently released version of `move_base`.

See #q301627 for some more context.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-08-26**:
Maybe this works https://askubuntu.com/questions/28372/how-do-i-get-and-modify-the-source-code-of-packages-installed-through-apt-get ?  Even if it does I think a regular catkin_ws + git clone is more likely to be what they want, and is on the path to pushing changes back to github and pull requests.